# Crear trigger en MySQL que inserte varias filas

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tengo dos tablas:

| Chequeras | Det_Cheques |
| --- | --- |
| ID | ID |
| N°_desde | N°_cheque |
| N°_hasta | Observacion |

Necesito crear un trigger o una manera de que, al momento de ingresar una nueva Chequera, automáticamente me inserte la cantidad de cheques (que seria la diferencia entre el `N°_desde` y `N°_hasta`) en la tabla `Det_Cheques`.

Por ejemplo:

Ingreso una nueva Chequera (`ID` = 1, `N°_desde` = 10, `N°_hasta` = 15) automáticamente, en la tabla `Det_Cheques`, se deben insertar 5 registros:

| ID | N°_cheque | Observacion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 11 |  |
| 3 | 12 |  |
| 4 | 13 |  |
| 5 | 14 |  |
| 6 | 15 |  |

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Agrega el código del disparador, lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Estás olvidando lo más importante de este asunto, ¿cómo vas a relacionar estos elementos de `Det_Cheques` con la Chequera que acabas de insertar? No hay ningún campo que los relacione, por lo que perderás la relación que hubo entre el registro original y los creados.